# Angular8 PrimeNG Radio Button unchecked while drag and drop

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have different set input elements, in that I have implemented drag and drop between form inputs.

While drag and drag the radio button element, it's unchecked but `ngModel` hold that previously selected value.

Here is my code what I have tried,

```
<div class="col-12">
                                Conditional match-{{condition?.conditionalOperator}}
                              <p-radioButton name="radio_{{condition.uuid}}" inputId="i1_{{condition.uuid}}" required class="mr-2" value="OR" label="Any" [(ngModel)]="condition.conditionalOperator"></p-radioButton>
                              <p-radioButton name="radio_{{condition.uuid}}" inputId="i2_{{condition.uuid}}" required value="AND" label="All" [(ngModel)]="condition.conditionalOperator"></p-radioButton>
                            </div>
```

**Here is a screenshot before drag and drop**
[image]

**Here is a screenshot after drag and drop**
[image]

Thanks in Advance